# Unexpected character sequence in member name

Tags: json

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong with this json data. Visual Studio says: "Unexpected character sequence in member name", online validators say similar. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
{
  {
    "id": 0,
    "flair": "LowerFlair",
    "flairtext": "Give it up!",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0.200
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "flair": "LowerMiddleFlair",
    "flairtext": "You might need more batting practice",
    "min": 0.201,
    "max": 0.249
  }
}
```

Comment: the outer `{}` should be `[]`. Otherwise it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have an object inside another object, in your case you should have a key:value, ex:

```
{
  "records":[
   {
     "id": 0,
     "flair": "LowerFlair",
     "flairtext": "Give it up!",
     "min": 0,
     "max": 0.200
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "flair": "LowerMiddleFlair",
     "flairtext": "You might need more batting practice",
     "min": 0.201,
     "max": 0.249
   }
  ]
 }
```

or an array:

```
[
   {
     "id": 0,
     "flair": "LowerFlair",
     "flairtext": "Give it up!",
     "min": 0,
     "max": 0.200
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "flair": "LowerMiddleFlair",
     "flairtext": "You might need more batting practice",
     "min": 0.201,
     "max": 0.249
   }      
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your root is an object, it should be an array.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "flair": "LowerFlair",
    "flairtext": "Give it up!",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0.200
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "flair": "LowerMiddleFlair",
    "flairtext": "You might need more batting practice",
    "min": 0.201,
    "max": 0.249
  }
]
```